# An elegant way to find the range of functions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the range of the function  $ y=$ $\Large\frac {x}{x^2+1}$. My idea was to express the value of $x$ in terms of $y$. But that yields a very messy solution involving the quadratic formula. Is there any elegant way to find the range if the use of calculus is allowed?

Comment: And could you define what you mean by "elegant"?  Because the notions of "elegance" is a subjective judgement, and without objective criteria used to operationalize "elegance", it is a matter of personal opinion, which is a reason for closure of a question.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the extreme values by using derivatives but since you already found the following bounds, you just need to show that these belong to the range; continuity does the rest.

---

From $(x-1)^2 \ge 0 \implies x^2+1 \ge 2x$, you have:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1} \le \frac{1}{2}$$
and from $(x+1)^2 \ge 0 \implies x^2+1 \ge -2x$, you have: 
$$-\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{x}{x^2+1}  $$
Now note that:

- $f(1) = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and $f(-1) = -\tfrac{1}{2}$;
- $f$ is continuous, so it takes all values between $-\tfrac{1}{2}$ and $\tfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer among all the others.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1) Note that the function $y=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is continuous in the domain $(-\infty,+\infty)$. So the range is the interval between the  absolute minimum and the absolute maximum of the function.

2)Note that the limits at $\pm \infty$ of the function are $0$.

3) take the derivative and search the minimum and maximum  values of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=\cfrac{x}{x^2+1}$ is odd, so it suffices to determine the range for $x \ge 0\,$, then add its symmetric across $0$.

For $x \gt 0\,$, the well known (and easy to prove e.g. by AM-GM) inequality $x+\cfrac{1}{x} \ge 2$ gives $f(x)=\cfrac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}} \le \cfrac{1}{2}$ with equality at $x=1$. Since $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous, it follows that the image of $[0,\infty)$ is $\left[0,\cfrac{1}{2}\right]$ and, since $f$ is odd, its range is $\left[0,\cfrac{1}{2}\right] \cup \left[-\cfrac{1}{2},0\right] = \left[-\,\cfrac{1}{2},\cfrac{1}{2}\right]\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$y=\frac{x}{1+x^2}\implies yx^2-x+y=0$
.
Now Use Shreedharacharya's formula to get $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$.

Value of $x$ is meaningful only if $y \neq 0$ & $1-4y^2\ge0\implies y\in [-1/ 2,1/2]$-{0}

& if $x=0$ then $y=0$,so $y=0$ is in the range.Hence $-1/2\leq y \leq 1/2 $.

Comment: You need to take the case $y=0$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is so messy express $x$ as a function of $y$.

You can write

$$yx^2-x+y=0$$

$1)$ $y=0$ iff $x=0$.

$2)$ If $y\ne 0$ then:

$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$

and once $x\in \Bbb R$ we must have:

$$1-4y^2\ge 0 \to y\in \left[-\frac{1}{2},0\right[\cup \left]0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

once we know that $0$ is in the range then it is

$$\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Show that $$-\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{x}{x^2+1}\le \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, I did it using the identity $(x+1)^2$. I also showed that it is greater than or equal to negative one half.But is that going to be enough?

Comment: you can prove this also with calculus

Comment: @user161940 You would also have to show that the function is continuous in the interval.

Comment: Note the difference between the other answers and yours.  All others, provide solid arguments, and then conclude exactly the conclusion you wrote, and expect the OP to understand why your conclusion is valid (or not, because you provide no reason why your statement should be believed.  Or are you simply reporting what you learned from WA?

Comment: i think it is not difficult to see and to prove that $$\frac{x}{x^2+1}\le \frac{1}{2}$$