# Determining range of a function

Tags: functions

I was trying to determine the domain and range of a function. The function is: $$y = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$$
I determined the domain which is $\mathbb{R}$. In this equation, when the value of $x$ is 0, the value of $y$ is $0$.  Then, I tried to determine the range by this equation: 
$$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4y^2}}{2y}$$ 
I derived the equation from previous equation using quadratic equation formula. In this method we can see, the range is $\{-0.5 \leq y < 0\}$ and $\{0 < y \leq 0.5\}$. Zero cannot be a range because the denominator cannot be zero. 
But if $0$ is not in the range, then we do not find any value for $x$ when $x$ is $0$ which is a contradiction of the definition of a function. Where is the fault?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2199960/42969.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that: 1) this is not a quadratic function, (2) $0$ is clearly in the range: take $x = 0$ to obtain $y = 0/(0^2 + 1) = 0$, your reason why it can't be makes no sense and simply has nothing to do with the range of the function, and (3) taking $x = 1$ gives $y = \frac{1}{2}$, so clearly the rest of your reasoning is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

A reason you get a contradiction is that you got too far ahead before looking to see where you were going. Indeed if we want to solve for $x$ in
$$y = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1},$$
the first steps could be
$$y (x^2 + 1) = x,$$
$$y x^2 + - x + y = 0.$$
Now if $y \neq 0$ this is a quadratic equation that can be solved by the quadratic formula, but if $y = 0$ then it is a linear equation that can be solved much more simply:
$$ -x = 0, $$
$$ x = 0.$$

Indeed,  you should simply take note of the obvious fact that $0$ is in the range of the function (since $y= 0$ when $x = 0$) and look for *additional* possible non-zero values of $y,$
that is, to look for any possible ways that $y \neq 0.$
Your quadratic formula then finds the rest of the range for you.

Answer (score 0):

An idea what to do with this kind of questions: assume $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$ belongs to the function's range, then there exists $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ (the function's domain) s.t.

$$a=f(x)=\frac x{x^2+1}\implies ax^2-x+a=0\implies \Delta=1-4a^2\ge0\implies |a|\le\frac12$$

and thus you get that **it must be that** $\;-\frac12\le a\le\frac12\;$ , and the range of the function is *waaaay* different from what you thought.

Comment: I do not understand why you say the range is way different from the one proposed by the OP.  The OP found all of the same values but was confused by his method.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Perhaps, The OP's original post wasn't written with LaTeX and I thought I read something involving intervals with $\;5\;$ ...That's why I wrote what I wrote.